# I want to have multiple sliders on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

This is what i tried to do i want the program to get the product number and then choose the right article to show, the first one works fine but the second one doesn't i think i need another implementation rather than using the parent element.

```js
var ids = ["view_0", "view_1", "view_2", "view_3"]
let current_id = 0;

function next(product) {
 var parent =document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).parentElement.id;
  if(product==parent){
  let last_array_position = ids.length;
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.remove("show");
  current_id++;
  if (current_id >= last_array_position) {
    current_id = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.add("show");
}
}
```

```css
<style>
  #1 img {
  display: none;
}

#1 img.show {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiple Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <article id="1">
    <img  class="show" id="view_0"></img>
    <img id="view_1"></img>
    <img id="view_2"></img>
    <img id="view_3"></img>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next(1)">></button>
  </article>
    <article id="2">
      <img  class="show" id="view_0"></img>
      <img id="view_1"></img>
      <img id="view_2"></img>
      <img id="view_3"></img>
      <button><</button>
      <button onclick="next(2)">></button>



  </article>

</body>
```

Getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

```js
var ids = ["view_0", "view_1", "view_2", "view_3"]
let current_id = 0;

function next() {
  let last_array_position = ids.lastIndexOf;
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.remove("show");
  current_id = current_id + 1;
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.add("show");
  if (current_id < last_array_position) {
    current_id = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiple Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="product1">
    <p class="show" id="view_0">1</p>
    <p id="view_1">2</p>
    <p id="view_2">3</p>
    <p id="view_3">4</p>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next()">></button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to call the `lastIndexOf()` method with an argument.

Comment: I think you mean `ids.length`.

Comment: This bit of code: `if (current_id < last_array_position) { current_id = 0; }` is very odd, because `current_id` is always going to be less than `last_array_position`, because you reset it to 0 every time you call `next()`. I think you want `if (current_id === last_array_position)` or `if (current_id === last_array_position - 1)`... You also don't need to calculate `last_array_position` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the element which is going out of bounds because the condition check is happening later. You need to check the condition before accessing the `classList` and adding `show` to it. Also, you can keep `last_array_position = ids.length` outside your function as that is not gonna change.

Here's a more simpler solution for more than one slider section in a page:

```js
function next(productId) {
  var tags = document.getElementById(productId).getElementsByTagName("p");
  var index;
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (tags[i].className == "show") {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  tags[index].classList.remove("show")
  index = (index + 1) == tags.length ? 0 : index + 1;
  tags[index].classList.add("show")
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiple Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="product1">
    <p class="show" id="view_1_0">1</p>
    <p id="view_1_1">2</p>
    <p id="view_1_2">3</p>
    <p id="view_1_3">4</p>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next('product1')">></button>
  </div>

  <div id="product2">
    <p class="show" id="view_2_0">1</p>
    <p id="view_2_1">2</p>
    <p id="view_2_2">3</p>
    <p id="view_2_3">4</p>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next('product2')">></button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: how could i have multiple sliders in the same page

Comment: Can't get you? Isn't this what you implemented in this example?

Comment: i want to have two of these on the same page how could i do that

Comment: function next(product) {
 var parent =document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).parentElement.id;
  if(product==parent){
  let last_array_position = ids.length;
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.remove("show");
  current_id++;
  if (current_id >= last_array_position) {
    current_id = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.add("show");
}
}

Comment: thanks , i was thinking about an simpler implementation for this as it would be quite tedious if i wanted to have even more sliders

Comment: I was thinking the same :) I've updated the answer with the simplest possible solution. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an array is in the `length` property, not `lastIndexOf` (that's a method that you use to search for the last occurrence of a value).

You need to check if the index exceeds that *before* you try to use the element.

Your `if` statement also has the wrong condition, it should be `>=`, not `<`.

```js
var ids = ["view_0", "view_1", "view_2", "view_3"]
let current_id = 0;

function next() {
  let last_array_position = ids.length;
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.remove("show");
  current_id++;
  if (current_id >= last_array_position) {
    current_id = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
#product1 p {
  display: none;
}

#product1 p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiple Slider</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="product1">
    <p class="show" id="view_0">1</p>
    <p id="view_1">2</p>
    <p id="view_2">3</p>
    <p id="view_3">4</p>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next()">></button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thank you so much :>